# jboss 7.1.1 webservices suddenly stopped working

Tags: spring, web-services, jboss7.x

I have a deployed and public app available where everything is working. The rest of the team is working on a new release and before releasing it, we started running tests at everything.

Out of the blue, the web services that we use to communicate with a payment gateway stopped working and started returning a null pointer exception.
This is something that is happening on all machines in the development team.

Even the same code that is deployed on the server results in the same nullpointerexception.
We have tried in other servers and the result is the same.

We are using jboss 7.1.1 and the stack trace of the crash is this:
Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

> 15:53:23,199 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 15:53:23,200 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ASMHelper.getClassCode(ASMHelper.java:170)
>
> 15:53:23,200 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.WrapperClassGenerator.generateMessagePart(WrapperClassGenerator.java:320)
>
> 15:53:23,201 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.WrapperClassGenerator.createWrapperClass(WrapperClassGenerator.java:234)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is resolved. The company that developed the payment gateway changed the WSDL without notifying anyone...
The issue was caused by the client trying to access a WSDL different from the one he was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to mind:

1. Is the payment gateway still up? Try using a tool such as SOAP UI to see if you get the same problem on another tool. SOAP UI will allow you to quickly test the web service.
2. Set a break point in your code and step through to determine where the problem is.

It sounds like something is either not configured correctly or a service is down etc. You should be able to set a break point quite easily and then use standard debugging techniques.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
After a bit more debugging I found out the problem.
The company that made the payment gateway decided to change the WSDL without notifying anyone...
The issue is resolved, after a lot of hours wasted :(